# Calling @classmethod's super, which calls another classmethod

Tags: python-3.x, super, superclass, class-method

Could not find an answer here, so posting this.
Was getting this error:

```
main() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

For this code, where `B` tries to extend `A`'s method, which intern calls an additional class method.

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def run(cls):        
        cls.main(cls)

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        """Override and set main logic here
        """
        pass


class B(A):        
    title = "Hello"
    @classmethod
    def run(cls, name):
        cls.name = name
        super().run()

    @classmethod
    def main(cls, *args):
        """Override and set main logic here
        """
        print(cls.title, cls.name)

B.run('Bob')   # Hello Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

`super()` passes:

```
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.B'>)
```

into `B.main()` when `A.run()` calls it:
Can make `B` handle the extra parameter by just collecting any additional positional arguments:

```
def main(cls, *args):
```